# Why does my form height increase after showing error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning frontend and i am trying to do a challenge from [frontendmentor](https://www.frontendmentor.io/) and it also includes some form validation.
so whenever the user submits the form, if any input field is empty a small error image should appear in the input and also there should be a line below the input stating that the input field should not be empty.

so when there is an error, the image and the line appears but the height of my form increases.
I gave body and the enclosing container a min height but still its not working..

challenge link
[challenge link](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/intro-component-with-signup-form-5cf91bd49edda32581d28fd1)

codepen link [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mihir16/pen/qBZeyPY)

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Intro component with sign up form</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>  Learn to code by watching others</h1>
      <p>See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. Watching scripted tutorials is great, 
        but understanding how developers think is invaluable. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="heading">
          <p>Try it free 7 days <span>then $20/mo. thereafter</span></p>
        </div>
        <form action="#">
          <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
            <img class="error-image" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
            <p class="error-text">First Name cannot be empty</p>
          </div>
          

          <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
            <img class="error-image" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
            <p class="error-text">Last Name cannot be empty</p>
          </div>
          

          <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
            <img class="error-image" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
            <p class="error-text">Looks like this is not an email</p>
          </div>
          
          
          <div> <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <img class="error-image" src="images/icon-error.svg" alt="">
            <p class="error-text">Password cannot be empty</p>
          </div>
         

          <button type="submit">Claim your free trial</button>
          <p>By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our <span>Terms and Services</span></p>
          
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');


*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
--Red: hsl(0, 100%, 74%); 
--Green: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);
--Blue: hsl(248, 32%, 49%);
--DarkBlue: hsl(249, 10%, 26%);
--GrayishBlue: hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
}

body{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 1440px;
}

.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/bg-intro-desktop.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
    background-color: var(--Red);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 160px;
}

.container .left{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

.container .left h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 30px;    
}

.container .left p{
    opacity: 0.8;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
}
.container .right{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.container .right form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 35px 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container .right form div input{
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    padding: 17px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .right form div input:focus{
    border: 2px solid var(--GrayishBlue);
    border-top: 1px solid var(--DarkBlue);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--DarkBlue);
}

.container .right .heading{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--Blue);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 18px 35px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 0px  rgb(211, 108, 108) ;
}

.container .right form button{
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--Green);
    padding: 18px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.09rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px hsl(154, 48%, 38%);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.container .right form button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.container .right form div input::placeholder{
    font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.container .right form:last-child{
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--GrayishBlue);
}

.container .right form:last-child span{
    color: var(--Red);
    font-weight: 600;
}

.container .right .heading span{
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.container .right form div{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container .right form div .error-image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 25px;
    display: none;

}

.container .right form div .error-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 2px;
    color: var(--Red);
    display: none;
}

.container .right form div.error .error-image,.container .right form div.error .error-text{
    display: block;
}

.container .right form div.error input{
    border: 2px solid var(--Red);
}

.container .right form div.error{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}



@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .container{
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        background-image: url(images/bg-intro-mobile.png);
    }

    .container .left{
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 80px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

    .container .left h1{
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .container .left p{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .container .right{
        width: 90%;
    }

    .container .right .heading{
        padding: 30px 0;
        margin-bottom: 25px
    }

    .container .right{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .container .right form div input{
        margin-bottom: 16px
    }
    .container .right form:last-child{
       line-height: 1.4rem;
    }

    .container .right form{
        padding: 25px 30px
    }
}
```

js

```
const form = document.querySelector('.container .right form');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.container .right form div input');

form.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        if(!input.value){
            input.parentElement.classList.add('error');
        }
        else{
            input.parentElement.classList.remove('error');   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The error messages obviously take up extra room when they're displayed. `min-height` only restricts the minimum height, not the maximum height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a fixed height on your error containers. When you don't set a height, and the container has a display value of none, then the height of that container will be 0px.
As you have set a min-height, the containers will default to this when display is none.

I imagine that when you give this a container a display value of block, the divs height ends up being larger than that of the min-height value.

Either increase the min-height value or set a fixed height on your error containers.